# How to get Named Entity Extraction using GATE Annie in Java?

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition, gate

I am newbie in **GATE ANNIE**. I tried **GATE GUI interface** and got experience to do task on it. I wanted to know how can I implement **Named Entity Extraction** in Java?

I did R&D but unable to find any tutorial regarding **Named Entity Extraction**.

Is there any code available to find out **Named Entity Extraction** in **GATE ANNIE** in **Java**?

Comment: Quick Start with GATE Embedded: https://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:api:embed

Comment: @dedek: Do you have any sample code in Java for NER using GATE ANNIE ?

Comment: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/javadoc/src-html/sheffield/examples/StandAloneAnnie.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import gate.*;
import gate.creole.ANNIEConstants;
import gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class AnnieNerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Gate.setGateHome(new File("C:\\Program Files\\GATE_Developer_8.1"));
        Gate.init();

        LanguageAnalyser controller = (LanguageAnalyser) PersistenceManager
                .loadObjectFromFile(new File(new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(),
                        ANNIEConstants.PLUGIN_DIR), ANNIEConstants.DEFAULT_FILE));

        Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("corpus");
        Document document = Factory.newDocument(
                "Michael Jordan is a professor at the University of California, Berkeley.");
        corpus.add(document); controller.setCorpus(corpus); 
        controller.execute();

        document.getAnnotations().get(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("Person", "Organization", "Location")))
            .forEach(a -> System.err.format("%s - \"%s\" [%d to %d]\n", 
                    a.getType(), Utils.stringFor(document, a),
                    a.getStartNode().getOffset(), a.getEndNode().getOffset()));

        //Don't forget to release GATE resources 
        Factory.deleteResource(document); Factory.deleteResource(corpus); Factory.deleteResource(controller);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Person - "Michael Jordan" [0 to 14]
Organization - "University of California" [37 to 61]
Location - "Berkeley" [63 to 71]
```

---

### Jars

two possibilities:

1. Manual

[Quick Start with GATE Embedded](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch7.html#sec:api:embed):

> add `$GATE_HOME/bin/gate.jar` and the JAR ﬁles in `$GATE_HOME/lib` to the Java CLASSPATH (`$GATE_HOME` is the GATE root directory)

2. Maven

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>uk.ac.gate</groupId>
       <artifactId>gate-core</artifactId>
       <version>8.4</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the code. You saved my time. One question more, which JARS, you used ?

Comment: @dedek Thank you for this code, really helpful. I wish to run the TwitIE pipeline, which is a gate Plugin. Do you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: @Mr.Phil the only change should be in the GAPP file: `PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(new File(Gate.getPluginsHome(), "Twitter/resources/twitie-english-only.gapp"))`

Answer (score 0):

for development and using in java code. It is better to use gate embedded.

pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.gate</groupId>
        <artifactId>gate-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.ac.gate.plugins/annie -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uk.ac.gate.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>annie</artifactId>
        <version>8.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Main.java file in src

```
import gate.*;
import gate.creole.ANNIEConstants;
import gate.creole.Plugin;
import gate.creole.ResourceReference;
import gate.util.persistence.PersistenceManager;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Gate.init();
        Plugin anniePlugin = new Plugin.Maven("uk.ac.gate.plugins", "annie", "8.6");
        Gate.getCreoleRegister().registerPlugin(anniePlugin);
        URL annieFile = new ResourceReference(anniePlugin, "resources/" + ANNIEConstants.DEFAULT_FILE).toURL();

        LanguageAnalyser controller = (LanguageAnalyser) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromUrl(annieFile);

        Corpus corpus = Factory.newCorpus("corpus");
        Document document = Factory.newDocument("Michael Jordan is a professor at the University of California, Berkeley.");
        corpus.add(document);
        controller.setCorpus(corpus);
        controller.execute();


        for (Annotation obj : document.getAnnotations().get(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Person", "Organization", "Location")))) {
            System.out.print("type : " + obj.getType());
            System.out.print("\t data : " + Utils.stringFor(document, obj));
            System.out.print("\t start : " + obj.getStartNode().getOffset());
            System.out.println("\t end : " + obj.getEndNode().getOffset());
        }
        Factory.deleteResource(document);
        Factory.deleteResource(corpus);
        Factory.deleteResource(controller);
    }
}
```

example code https://github.com/hsali/gate-developer-annie-plugin-example